# How do I get oh my zsh to work properly with iterm2?

Tags: iterm2, oh-my-zsh

When I try to use the zsh shell with iterm2, all colors set by zsh disappear. So git diffs, etc. Show as all one color. I have selected zsh as the shell successfully, but it seems to get overwritten. I have done `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.

Comment: Are you using a particular iterm2 theme?

Comment: Also perhaps try oh-my-zsh?

Comment: I should have said, I am using oh-my-zsh. No iterm theme.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this happened, but my color settings for iterm were set all the way up on minimum contrast, causing the colors settings to not show even though they were applied correctly. From iterm, `preferences -> profiles -> colors -> slide minimum contrast setting to the middle`.

Answer (score 0):

the slider by iTerm -> Preference -> Profiles -> Colorsy =>Cursor Boost is they "Off/left"? 
When this slider is on the middle - there is the same effect as the colors have not enough contrast.